# Express Session not working with DialogFlow

Tags: express, session, dialogflow-es

I have deployed an Express app on Heroku, set my web hook on the address and use my DG agent to make post request to the endpoint on Heroku.
The webhook passes over parameters's body to another web service and that's fine. I need to keep track of the cookie the web service passes back in order to send it back to keep the context of the conversation.

At the moment I am saving a file on the server with the Express's session id (req.session.id) and the cookie value. Everything works if I make POST call via Postman or via form, so let's say the web application is tracking sessions properly. 
On the contrary, if I test my webhook with the DialogFlow agent, I receive a new session id per each request to my endpoint on Heroku.
I don't understand why... What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can rely on the request from DialogFlow maintaining a cookie for you.

We are using DialogFlow, Google Actions, and Node.js. We retain session information by including data in the response we send back, which we then read when the next request comes in. When writing a response we put our session data (JSON) on the assistant.data attribute. When receiving a request we get session data from the incoming event.body.

We had considered trying to live off a unique ID of the incoming request, such as a user ID or device ID, but did not pursue it.

Comment: thanks @NinePlanFailed, just a clarification: I know DG can't store a cookie for me, infact I do this on Heroku server, by saving a file via FileStore module. The point is this: everytime I send a query to DG and it invokes my web hook, I get a different sessionID each time. This doesn't happen if I use Postman or a form. I might have a clue: in curl it happens the same as DG, but if I set the options for writing/reading cookie, everything works fine.

Comment: @Ethan I think that is it, DG does not retain cookies nor should it as it does not represent a single user, whereas curl and PostMan have the ability to handle cookies.